# How to change a property for all ComboBoxes?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have several `ComboBoxes` in my form. I need to change their `DropDownStyle`. Is there any way to do this. These all `ComboBoxes` were in 5 Tabs.

Below I do some example.

```
For Each tbxControl As Control In Me.Controls
    If TypeOf (tbxControl) Is TextBox Then
        tbxControl.ForeColor = Color.Black
    End If
Next
```

Sample Of The code as follows

```
 With cboProvince
                    .DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown
                    .Text = CStr(odrEmployeeMasterRecordsSearch("Province_Name"))
                End With
                With cboDistrict
                    .DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown
                    .Text = CStr(odrEmployeeMasterRecordsSearch("District_Name"))
                End With
                With cboPostalCode
                    .DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown
                    .Text = CStr(odrEmployeeMasterRecordsSearch("PostOffice"))
                End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have works because `ForeColor` is a property of the `Control` class, therefore you can access that property on a `Control` reference. `DropDownStyle` is a property of the `ComboBox` class so you need to cast as that type. This code will filter and cast in one go:

```vb
For Each cmbx In Controls.OfType(Of ComboBox)()
    cmbx.DropDownStyle = DropDownStyle.DropDownList
Next
```

Note that this only works for `ComboBoxes` that are directly on the form and not in a `Panel` or other container.

For the record, you could have done something similar with your original code:

```vb
For Each tbxControl In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
    tbxControl.ForeColor = Color.Black
Next
```

Comment: Thank You jmcilhinney. My comboboxes are in the Tab. I think I cannot do this. Thank You Verymuch again.

Comment: @Mark, the code I provided, as with your example, uses the `Controls` collection of the form. If your controls have a different parent then just use the `Controls` collection of that, e.g. `myTabPage.Controls`. The issue arises when you are talking about controls with different parents. That requires a little extra work.

Comment: jmcilhinney, can you please show me some example.